# Setting different permissions for different kinds of requests on serializer based api (using router)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF and working on a single URL for handling all user operations such as LIST, GET, POST, etc.

I have used a router but I'm unable to find how I should go about tweaking the permissions such as...

- Even anonymous users can create users.
- Only registered users (or admins, as an exception) can delete their own posts.
  And so on..

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from .api import UserAPI
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter


urlpatterns = [

    # path('register/<int:pk>', UserAPI.as_view(), name='user_create'),


]

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user', UserAPI)
urlpatterns = [

              ] + router.urls
```

**Serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.forms import ValidationError


User = get_user_model()


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
        extra_kwargs = {'last_name': {'required': True}}

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        user = User.objects.create(email=validated_data['email'],
                                   first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
                                   last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
                                   )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

**api.py**

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model  # used custom user model
from rest_framework import mixins
from .serializers import UserSerializer

User = get_user_model()


class UserAPI(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom permission class and define what all things you need.
Example

```
from rest_framework.compat import is_authenticated
from rest_framework import permissions

class MyCustomPermissionClass(permissions.BasePermission):
    def is_authenticated(self, request):
        return request.user and is_authenticated(request.user)

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if view.action == 'create':  # create new user by anyone
            return True
        if is_authenticated(request) and view.action == 'destroy' and request.user == post_created_by_user:
            return True
        # add all other conditions you want to implement
        return False  # default case
```

and add the permission class to your views

```
from .permissions import MyCustomPermissionClass
```

class UserAPI(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    **permission_classes = (MyCustomPermissionClass,)**
One thing you should remember, **unless a boolean `True` is returned from permission class, you won't get the permisson to access the corresponding view**
Read more info about [DRF- Custom Permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)

**Update on 31-07-2018**
`rest_framework.compat.is_authenticated` is depricated. **`request.user.is_authenticated`** will do the samething

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class MyCustomPermissionClass(permissions.BasePermission):
    def is_authenticated(self, request):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if view.action == 'create':  # create new user by anyone
            return True
        if self.is_authenticated(request) and view.action == 'destroy' and request.user == post_created_by_user:
            return True
        # add all other conditions you want to implement
        return False  # default case
```

Comment: What do you think about [DryRestPermissions](https://github.com/dbkaplan/dry-rest-permissions)? I think this makes it much easier. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry bro, I didn't try that package yet :(

Comment: :D Thanks anyway

Comment: I recently upgraded to drf 3.8
Apparently it does not support from rest_framework.compat import is_authenticated. 
I fixed this part. However, how do I get post_created_by_user?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: How would I get    post_created_by_user?

Comment: It's your logic. It depends on your models, where you using the permission class etc

Comment: you said, *Only registered users (or admins, as an exception) can delete their own posts. And so on*, which means, I can delete particular object either I might be the **owner** of particular object or **I must be the Admin**

Answer (score 0):

permissions.py

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class UserPermissions(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # request.user.is_authenticated to make sure user is authed
        # view.action == 'create' will allow Even anonymous users can create users.
        return request.user.is_authenticated or view.action == 'create'

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # obj == request.user make sure the changeing(update/read/delete) user is itself and only itself.
        # if you want authed user can read and only myself can update\delete ,change it to obj == request.user or view.action == 'retrieve'
        return obj == request.user
```

views.py

```
class UserAPI(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (UserPermissions,)
```